# PySNMP MIB module failing when attempting to access function Counter64

Tags: python, mib, pysnmp

Attempting to run a MIB based SNMP script and I running into an issue. It is unable to run the function Counter64 though I know that the module which contains that function is installed. the MIB module is automatically generated so I attempted to regenerate it once the missing module was installed, but it didn't resolve the issue.

The code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7

from pysnmp.smi import builder, view, error
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen

cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()
mibBuilder = builder.MibBuilder()
mibSources = mibBuilder.getMibSources() + ( builder.DirMibSource( '/path/to/command/mibs', ), )
mibBuilder.setMibSources( *mibSources )
print mibBuilder.getMibSources()
mibBuilder.loadModules( 
    'NS-MIB-smiv2',
    )
mibView = view.MibViewController( mibBuilder )
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, \
                 varBindTable = cmdGen.nextCmd( 
    cmdgen.CommunityData( 'Name', 'Community' ),
    cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget( ( 'IP Address', 161 ) ),
    ( ( '', 'serverName' ), ),
    )

print varBindTable
```

I know the variables for the environment are correct as I can query them using man ually assigned OIDs without any problem. The Traceback I'm receiving is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "./snmpcollectorexample.py", line 12, in <module>

    'NS-MIB-smiv2',

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysnmp-4.2.1-py2.7.egg/pysnmp/smi/builder.py", line 221, in loadModules

pysnmp.smi.error.SmiError: MIB module "/path/to/command/mibs/NS-MIB-smiv2.py" load error: name 'Counter64' is not defined
```

Doesn anyone have recommendations? Counter64 is a part of the pycopia-SMI Python module and I've confirmed that it is installed. But I'm unsure how to go about resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Located the issue. For some reason the `build-pysnmp-mib` wrapper when running my MIB through all the conversion commands was not adding the Counter64 entries into the `mibBuilder.importSymbols()`. Manually added it and it moved right along.